# Instrumentation fail when app use far jump 0x33 crash

Tags: dynamic-analysis, instrumentation, pintool, dynamorio

Do you known any dbi tool that support instrumentation of application that use far jump 0x33?

P.S. pin, dymanoRIO don't support far jump 0x33.